# A method to prevent i-cache loss in a virtual machine?

Tags: c++, virtual-machine, interpreter

I am currently working on a bytecode interpreter/executor - sort of like Blueprints for Unreal Engine 4.

My current implementation of the compiler embeds native function addresses in the bytecode. These addresses are read and executed like function-pointers.

The bytecode doesn't change at runtime, so is there a way I can get the execution machine to not cause the CPU to jump all over the codebase?

Comment: What do you mean by *"not cause the GPU to jump all over the codebase?"*? What is jumping all over your codebase and why?

Comment: @UnholySheep my bad, I actually meant CPU. I edited the post. My understanding is that because the call is made through a function pointer, the CPU instructions cannot be inlined, and so it'll jump somewhere elsei n the codebase to execute that function. Is there a way I can prevent this from happening and somehow 'inline' this function call?

Comment: You could probably create hardcoded native functions, which call the functions directly instead of going via a function pointer. However that will add another system to the mix and the function calls may still not be inlined (or inlining may have negative performance effects) if the function to be called is too big. Did you profile to make sure that this indirection is an actual performance bottleneck?

Comment: If you create native functions (as @UnholySheep suggested), like mostly putting the opcodes there to call the functions, the branch prediction of the CPU may work better than with function pointers read from a memory array.